# Avoid Items in List to shift

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dynamic unordered list that is built for 3 list items however there maybe either one or two items in that list. My problem is that when there are one or two items in UL my contents get shifted up. How can I avoid this ?

HTML:

```
 <html><head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">


      <div id="colDow">
                <div id="colLef">
            <ul id="days">

        <div id="colRig">
            <ul class="format" id="schedule1">
            <li> Event 3</li>
              <li>test this space</li>
              <li>fit everthing and beyond</li>
          </ul>
            <ul class="format" id="schedule2">
            <li> Event 3</li>
              <li>test this space</li>
              <li>fit everthing and beyond</li>
          </ul>
            <ul class="format" id="schedule3">
     <li> Event 3</li>
              <li>test this space</li>
              <li>fit everthing and beyond</li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- Bottom Right Time -->
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#000;
    font-size:100%;
    }

    #wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:2560px;
    max-height:1440px;
    }



#colDow {
    width:55.46%;
/* 710/1280 */

    float:left;
    height:88.75%;
/*  710/800 */
}

#colLef {
    width:35.21%;
/* 250/710 */
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}

#days {

    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:0px;

    }

#days li {
    font-size:2.25em;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    font-weight:lighter;
    margin:0 0 168px;
    background:#575757;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px; 
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-bottom: 168px;
}


#colRig {
/*  background:#fff; */
    width:63.09%;
    float:right;
    height:100%;
}

.format {
/*  background:red; */
    margin-top: 46px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.format li {
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    font-weight:lighter;
    font-size:1.5em;
/*  font-size: 1.846em; */
    height: 52px;
}
```

If you remove the first occurrence of "Event3" items get shifted up

Comment: Code has to go in the question, not on some 3rd party website.

Comment: The problem is with your markup. The days of no semantics are over. HTML5 comes with semantic elemnts. That means developers have to move on.

Comment: @Arun this was something that I was contemplating when I was building this site. It is not your typical site. It is dashboard. There are no menus sections etc..Hence I opted for this. Is this still doable with HTML5 semantic elements ?

Comment: No need of that. You could do dis with a ul hierarchy. wait for 5 minutes, ill put up a demo

Comment: @ArunAravind sounds good. By the way I guess you are right. I could actually do it with HTML5. One example of this would be, http://lsdemo.componentone.com/sales/. Even though I am not going to that level, its the idea that what I am trying to achieve can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

markup

```
<div class="event-listing">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>List 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>Event 3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>test this space
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>fit everything and beyond
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>List 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>Event 3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>test this space
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>fit everything and beyond
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>List 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>Event 3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>test this space
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>fit everything and beyond
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </u>
    </div>
```

css

```
.event-listing ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

This is what i understood from your menu. Let me know if im wrong

Comment: essentially yes. That is a simplified way of what I am trying to achieve. I didn't think of it from that aspect. Here is visual representation of what I was trying to do: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/prmbu

Comment: You could do this by applying styles to the li's and a's. pretty easy, neat and clean.

Answer (score 0):

.event-listing ul {
 min-height: 100px //set a minimum height
}

Set a minimum height so  your list areas won't get shifted up.  Sorry code not in tags.  I'm mobile right now.